# How do I POST a message with digest authentication using Node?

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I'm trying to POST a message to a MarkLogic application server with digest security using Node. The equivalent curl request works fine:

```
curl -v -X POST --anyauth -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -d '{"user-name":"joe", "password": "cool"}' http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/users
```

I tried using the [NPM request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), which says it supports digest requests. I was able to do a GET request successfully. Here's one attempt at POST:

```
request(
  {
    'url': 'http://localhost:8000/manage/v2/users',
    'method': 'POST',
    'auth': {
      'user': 'admin',
      'password': 'admin',
      'sendImmediately': false
    },
    'followRedirect': true,
    'followAllRedirects': true,
    'json': true,
    'body': {'user-name':'joe', 'password': 'cool'}
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    console.log('callback: ' + response.statusCode);
  }
);
```

That get's me a 401. The username and password are correct. I also tried like this:

```
request
  .post(
    'http://localhost:8000/manage/v2/users', 
    {'user-name':'joe', 'password': 'cool'})
  .auth('admin', 'admin', false)
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log('response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
  })
  .on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
  });
```

That gets me a 302. I feel like I must be missing something straightforward here.

- node v0.10.31
- MarkLogic 8.0-2

Comment: 302 is a redirect, have you tried following it?

Comment: The redirect appears to be the typical first response from a digest request, redirecting to the same URL but providing the cnonce and other info. The `followAllRedirects` option in the first attempt shown above is supposed to handle the redirect, but since that gives a 401, it seems it isn't doing so correctly.

Comment: I think `{ sendImmediately: false }` in the `auth` object is supposed to handle  the initial 401 in a digest negotiation; I'm not sure what's going wrong here. I've used `request` with ML7 extensively here: https://github.com/joemfb/mlpm-registry/blob/master/server.js; note `createOrUpdateUser()` and `saveRenderedMarkdown()` (and, yes, that code is a mess ;)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to have a simple solution: the curl request worked because I used localhost:8002; the node request failed because I used localhost:8000. Duh. The 302 redirect was telling me to use 8002 and I just missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty certain that the solution when I encountered this problem was to change the authentication setting in the app server from "digest" to "digestbasic". (Answering because I don't have enough rep to comment anywhere.)

Comment: If that is not an option or does not apply, just let me know so I can delete this answer, thanks.

Comment: That's definitely a valid approach for some circumstances, so it's worth leaving that answer here. I'd like to work with the out-of-the-box app server on port 8000 and it uses digest, hence my question.